# Is this a stuck fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, primary-fermentation

Here's what the fermentation has been so far.

Day 1: Not much

Day 2: 3 bubbles in the airlock every 2 seconds. Good krausen formed.

Day 3: 1 bubble per second

Day 4: 1 bubble per 2 seconds

Should the fermentation generally be more aggressive for more days?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds slow but ok. What kind of yeast did u use? some weiss  yeast is slow. if your OG is high it can be slow, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to "know" if fermentation is happening is to take a gravity reading and compare it to the OG value.  If it's going down, then everything is working according to plan.  If it's stable, then nothing is happening.

Bubbles are a terrible way to determine how the fermentation is going along. (Although very entertaining!) Especially true if you use plastic buckets.  You could have a small air leak along the lid such that the CO2 is escaping in another spot.

Especially with the solid krausen forming, I would not even give it a second thought.  All kinds of factors determine how vigorous and how quickly the yeast is going to behave.